# Decrypt a PKCS7 file in c++ with OpenSSL

Tags: c++, openssl, pkcs#7

I have a PKCS7 file, produced by M2Crypto python library, which looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN PKCS7-----
MIIBWAYJKoZIhvcNAQcDo[cut]
-----END PKCS7-----
```

Is is binary content encripted by a public key.

Now I need to decrypt it in C++, but it seems not to recognize this format. I tried `d2i_PKCS7_bio()` and  `SMIME_read_PKCS7()`, but I always get errors like:

```
8957:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1316:
8957:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:380:Type=PKCS7
```

and similar errors trying by command line like this:

```
openssl smime -decrypt -inform DER -binary -inkey privkey.pem
```

**EDIT**
I found the right command line option:

```
openssl cms -decrypt -in samplepkcs7.pem  -inkey privkey.pem -inform pem
```

Now I need to find the corresponding function in C++.

Maybe I'm wrong, but it's really hard to find documentation on this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is a PEM-format object; a DER-format object would look like garbage in a text editor (by virtue of being a binary format). Hence you want `PEM_read_PKCS7()`.

The OpenSSL documentation is inherently a mess, and it's very difficult to learn your way around without a guide of some sort. I recommend the O'Reilly [Network Security with OpenSSL](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596002701.do) text; while written for OpenSSL 0.9.6/0.9.7, it's still an excellent introduction to the library (the API hasn't changed very much) and will serve as a handy reference.

Comment: thanks. 2 questions:  can you explain me what exactly does that command line I wrote in the edit? and... I'm reading the book you suggested me now, and enc/decryption is done by EVP_*_init(), EVP_*_update(), EVP_*_Final(). On the web I found AES_cbc_encrypt() (without docs to how to use it, of course) of openssl/aes.h . Which method should be the best?

Comment: @vl1131 The `openssl cms` application handles pubkey-encrypted and signed data, which usually tends to be things like S/MIME email and whatnot; your command takes in such a datum specifically encoded in PEM form (signaled by `-inform pem`) and decrypts it using the private key supplied. As for encryption, just use EVP (the `EVP_CIPHER *` you want is returned by `EVP_aes_256_cbc()`) - it's a convenient abstraction layer that reduces the amount of work needed to support multiple ciphers (or replace a cipher if one is broken!).